# Calling npm from a php docker container

Tags: php, node.js, docker, npm

I have typical php web stack with docker. Amongst others I have a php container and a node container. On the production server they both don't share a volume.

Is it still possible to call npm commands (like `npm install`) from the php container, using the files inside the php container?

Or is it simpler to install node directly inside the php container, as all tutorial on the web seem to do?